# MS Test assertion checking

Tags: c#, unit-testing, tdd, mstest

I have wrote a test method using MS Test. I have written two assert for testing purpose. I have made the test case failed intentionally but I don't know which part of its failed.

```
public void CalculatorConstructorTest()
        {
            Calculator concreteObject = new Calculator();

            Assert.IsTrue(concreteObject == null, "Construction failed");
            Assert.IsTrue(concreteObject.Total == 0, "Value should be initially 0");
        }
```

As in the first assertion it will fail. Also I have maded Total greater than 0. So the second one will be also failed. But say one of them is valid. So how do I identify for which assert, my test case failed?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That is exactly why you should have one assert per test.

Comment: @HebeleHododo while i like the idea of that, when you do have a single branch of a function you're trying to test, and there's numerous things to check, if not doing multiple asserts is the alternative just copy and pasting the same test several times, once for each instance of an assert you'd want to do?  That seems like a big violation of DRY :D

Comment: @Kritner you could write a private method in your test class which returns the object you want to test. Thus, eliminating the need to copy-paste.

Comment: @HebeleHododo Many Testframeworks, including MsTest and NUnit have way of providing functionality to execute before each test is run (NUnit calls this `SetUp` for example). You could simply create a seperate TestClass for those complex szenarios where you have to test many things and have the asserts seperated by tests.

Comment: Why not use Assert.AreEqual()? That Assert method will show the mismatch between expected and actual values in the output log.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are many ways to do so:

#### Debugging

Try debugging the Test instead of just running it. This will cause an exception beeing raised at the failing assertion.

#### Inspecting Assertion Messages

You already povided some messages to your assertions, those will be visible in the test-explorers details-section after selecting the failed test. This is making it easier to determine which test-case failed (see screenshot below).

[image]

#### One Assertion per Testcase

As pointed out in the comments, try to have just one assertion per test-case where ever it is possible. This way its obvious which assertion failed simply because there is only one within a testcase.

#### Use fitting Assertions

Try to have more fitting assertions. In your case, you might try

```
    Assert.IsNull(concreteObject); 
    Assert.AreEqual(0, concreteObject.Total);
```

which will also tell you which of the two assertions failed by providing more precise automated messages as seen in the following screenshot:

[image]

However, the screenshot shows points out very well that even though we have 2 Assertions in the testcase, only one is marked as failed. The second one would also fail, but since the test is stopped at the first failing assertion, we'll not see that until the first assertion succeeds. This is why I would always go for **one assertion per test-case**.

Answer (score 0):

Try debugging the tests to see which part fails.